# C# - Default value of class

Tags: c#, .net

```
    class StyleProperty<T>
{

   static readonly StyleProperty<Object> INHERIT ;

    T value;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

}
```

Hello..
The above class sometimes should have the value INHERIT when value should not be used.. As 
c# doesnt allow overloading Properties i cant set Value=StyleProperty.Inherit. i must be of type T.

Any idea what to do there?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. What do you mean it should have the value INHERIT? INHERIT is a field, with a null value...

Comment: I think he wants to return the value of INHERIT if T is null. Some type of generic constraint out to do the trick I would think.

Comment: `INHERIT` has no value, its not instantiated.

Comment: Think like css. If it has value= inherit then it would look at another object of type StyleProperty outside this class(like a stack).. The problem is that if i have StyleProperty<Int> styleProp ;; .... then value would be int.. So there is no way to tell value= Inherit ,unless stylePross is equal to a object that "means" inherit..

Comment: Is the default value of `T` not correct?

Comment: If it inherits then T value shouldnt be used at all.. Null isnt a solution because if value=null i cant tell whether value should be null or value should be equal to parent's StyleProperty value..

Comment: that is the reason i need to include an extra inherit flag somehow.. because i cannot tell for example if user set it null or that it is null by default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, what about this:

```
class StyleProperty<T>
{
    T _Value;

    public StyleProperty(T inheritedValue)
    {
        _Value = inheritedValue;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return this._Value; }
        set { this._Value = value; }
    }        
}
```

Your first problem is how should the inherited value flow into the concrete instance? The only way i can think of would be the constructor. If the user doesn't like this value he can simply change it (to maybe the same value).

If you would use for inheritance some kind of global variable (but that wouldn't be inheritance, that would be a default value) you could also think about using a boolean flag which will be checked in the getter to find out if the backing store or the default should be used and it will set always to the opposite of its initial state within the setter.

```
class StyleProperty<T>
{
    T _Value;
    bool _UseBackingStore;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _UseBackingStore ? this._Value : INHERIT; }
        set { this._Value = value; _UseBackingStore = true; }
    }        
}
```

#### Update

To get a skin support into your application i think you need to take a different approach. All forms and gui controls you are using should implement some kind of interface (e.g. `ISkin`). Also your application should have some kind of `SkinSelector`. This one holds all informations about coloring, fonts, etc and it also gets a reference to the MainForm. Within the constructor it recursively runs through the Controls property of the form and checks if there are any controls implementing your interface (simply using `as ISkin` and check for `null`). If it is skinnable, simply set the colors, fonts, etc. of the control as defined within you `SkinSelector`. Sounds quite easy but the problem is, that you have to derive all gui controls and add your interface to them. So this is not such a complicated thing, but maybe a lot of work. Maybe you can test if Generics can help you out by using a `SkinWrapper<T> where T : Control` and an extension function like `ISkin ToSkinnableControl(this Control control)`). But this will only work if you need to change a few common properties, that are the same for all controls. If you need more skin control e.g. for the DataGridView or a ComboBox i think derivement is the only way to help you out.

Comment: well the second method is the one i used..First method's problem is that inherited value may change and that is a problem.. All i am trying to do is skin support for my application and simple properties dont work :(

Comment: i implemented something like dependency properties in .net as they werent available in my platform.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking for, but you can define a default value for a property like this:

```
[DefaultValue(<Value>)]
public T Value
{
    get { return this.value; }
    set { this.value = value; }
}
```